# Android, dynamic (tab)fragments with parameters from resource file?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-resources

I have built something similar to the FragmentTabHost that shows/hides/... a list of fragments. For now the layout of the host including the tab fragments were defined in a xml layout. Now I want to decouple the host from the hosted fragments. Creating and adding the fragments dynamically is not the real problem. But I don't see a nice way to store the parameters for the fragments in android resource files. 

a) How can I keep a list of tabs in a resource file to fill the tabHost with? I am thinking about an array of Strings containing the tab fragments class names. (Class.forName()..., new instance() ...). But this can't be the best idea?

b) How can I keep parameters for the tab fragments as convenient as with a normal layout file? I need a tab title and some fragments are actually containers and need to know which sublayouts they should use. So I have stylable attributes as well.

I hope I am overlooking something because at the moment I don't see any way to keep that data conveniently in a single resource file.

Comment: why don't you refer Google I/O 2014 code they have implemented this tab framework very efficiently and will answer all your doubts.

Comment: I am asking for a way to organize parameters in resource files that are to be used for dynamic fragments. Tabbing is just the example. The same question applies to non-tab activites with multiple dynamic fragments. Do you have a link to a solution?